# Why is my image uploader crashing over a resolution threshold of 2900 x 2176?

Tags: php, file, upload

Image size is not the problem here, because my image is 800 Kb.

My image upload works flawlessly at any resolution below 2900 x 2176. Over that threshold, it doesn't work. No image is uploaded. Why is that happening?

I'll put some code of my upload handler, just in case, but not sure if it's relevant.

The error is:

> PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8884 bytes) in /path/imageResizer.php on line 34 –

which refers to...

```
if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) { $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
```

Comment: *How* is it crashing? Is it just running out of memory? Any error messages?

Comment: Hi, the "uploading..." little gif keep showing, and no uploaded file appears in the directory. Regards

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8884 bytes) in /path/imageResizer.php on line 34

Comment: which refers to:   if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
 
         $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

Comment: Memory is definitely the problem then. 32M is a bit low for image resizement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of break occurs? Any errors being thrown?

Possibilities:

1. You're running out of memory. My guess is the imageResizer object and its methods are to blame. What is your current memory limit for php?

EDIT: As @deceze said, you can do use this function to temporarily raise the allocated memory:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '64MB');
```

1. imageResizer can't handle images of that resolution. Did you write that class yourself, or is it a library? I'm not familiar with it. Check specs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. It's your first guess. I edited my post. How can I change the memore allocated for that imageResizer.php? Regards

Comment: Excellent. Glad to have helped.

Comment: I just have a question about the ini_set(), do I need to put it into imageResizer.php? If so, before the whole imageResizer class declaration, or inside the Resizer function? Thanks a lot

Comment: That's a good question. Put it at the top of the controller script you had pasted here in your original post. I would use 64MB, and slowly increment that value based on any larger images you want to test. If it breaks again, raise it to 128MB.

Comment: Not a problem! Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

Image size *is* the problem. The file may only be 800 KB, but the image needs to be expanded into memory if you want to work with it. So you need roughly

```
2900 × 2176 × color depth × no. of channels
```

bytes of memory to store each individual pixel in memory to do anything with the image. This may easily surpass the regular PHP memory limit. Set a higher limit using, for example:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '500M');
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have reached the memory_limit. 
You should have a error message telling you that, I strongly recommand you to display those during development.

In the meantime,  you can add more memory for your imageReziser this way (if you have the right to use ini_set function on you server)

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

Comment: Hi, I edit my OP. It's a memory problem for image resizing. Regards